# DNS query using C++

Tags: c++, dns, email-spam, dnsbl

I have started working on the spam filtering in email for which i need to write a module which would query the DNS for blasklisted IP's. As a beginner can any please suggest me a good reading about DNS and making query to it using C++? . I searched around but wasn't able to get a very good source.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Try googling "c++ dns library"

Comment: Please put "query the DNS for blasklisted IP's" in contrete terms. What do you mean actually?

Comment: @Frunsi: I don't have exact knowledge, but I need to query DNSBL, to check whether a given IP is blacklisted or not for the purpose of email spam filtering.

Comment: @Piyush: Alright, DNSBL is the catchword. Now learn to know about DNSBL - what is it, how does it work. I don't know. But this catchword really should be an elementary part of your question!

Comment: @Piyush: maybe start at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL

Comment: @chris: I tried exact that search string "c++ dns library" and it brings me to [a useless comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959366/dns-query-using-c#comment11218858_8959366)...

Comment: @Leo sorry to have spoiled your interwebs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a beginner, you basically should know about one function, `gethostbyname`.

Then if you want to check `8.8.4.4` against `zen.spamhaus.org`, call

```
gethostbyname ("4.4.8.8.zen.spamhaus.org")
```

(note the reversed octets).

If this returns non-NULL, the IP is listed.

Now this is very primitive method with a number of drawbacks, but it works and you should try it before you move on to more sophisticated methods.

Comment: That's a hostlookup, not a DNS query.

Comment: @Leo: that's an attempt to solve a very specific problem posed by the OP. You are welcome to propose a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful. DNS has been a very fruitful place for exploitable code. It's remarkably easy to write vulnerable DNS software.

Most of the time you'll want to use an asynchronous resolver so that a slow or non-responsive DNS server cannot stall your application indefinitely. You just want it to stall delivery of a single specific mail. There's a handful of libraries packaged for Ubuntu:

```
libadns1-dev - Asynchronous-capable DNS client library and utilities
libc-ares-dev - library for asyncronous name resolves (development files)
libc-ares2 - library for asyncronous name resolves
firedns - Runtime binaries for firedns, an asynch. dns resolver library
libares-dev - asynchronous dns resolver library
libares0 - asynchronous dns resolver library
libfiredns-dev - Development files for firedns, an asynch. dns resolver library
libfiredns0.9 - Runtime libraries for firedns, an asynch. dns resolver library
libfiredns-dev - Development files for firedns, an asynch. dns resolver library
libfiredns0.9 - Runtime libraries for firedns, an asynch. dns resolver library
libowfat-dev - A reimplementation of libdjb
libudns-dev - async-capable DNS stub resolver library, development files
```

I've never used any of these so I can't give recommendations here. Sorry.

You might want to run a local recursive resolver to cache the results of lookups. This can reduce the amount of intelligence you have to program and allow your software to be significantly simpler. I have used the [`pdns-recursor`](http://doc.powerdns.com/built-in-recursor.html) before and loved it. Fantastic tool.